# Find the parametric equations of the line of intersection...

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

Find the parametric equations of the line of intersection of the planes x - z = 1 and x + 2y + 3z = 1.

I'm assuming it's something to do with cross product? Here's what I've set up:

x     y     z
1     0    -1   1
1     2     3   1

Answer (score 0):

The line of interesection of the planes will satisfy the equation of both the planes. Hence we must have,the equation of the line as
$$L=P_1+\lambda P_2$$
$$\Rightarrow L=(x - z-1)+\lambda (x + 2y + 3z-1)$$